# PCA and groups in R

Tags: r, pca

I hope that that question hasn't been asked before:
I'm trying to create a simple PCA in R. On that PCA, I wish to group/Color some of my data (some of the genes are located on the same chromosomes):

```
fviz_pca_ind(res.pca,
             col.ind = "cos2", # Color by the quality of representation
             gradient.cols = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"),
             repel = TRUE     # Avoid text overlapping
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Answer (score 0):

please refer this site. in short, you need a "habillage" arguments for the grouping.

http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/fviz-pca-quick-principal-component-analysis-data-visualization-r-software-and-data-mining

Comment: Hi BJK! Generally, you want to avoid answers that are just links. If you can answer the question, answer it. If you think someone else answered it nicely elsewhere, post the link in the comments.

Comment: Oops sorry, I can't comment on the post of others since my reputation is less than 50.